# how do i prevent extjs from refreshing a model after a save operation when the server does not return data

Tags: extjs

extjs appears to expect that during an update operation `model.save()` that the server will return the entire updated object back to the client, at which point extjs refreshes the local model with the result.

```
     localRecord.set(serverRecord.data);
```

but my server does not return the entire record after an `update`.  how do i prevent extjs from refreshing the local model?  i prefer to handle this in an overridden proxy as it hold all my other custom proxy settings.

Comment: here is what i have done, even thought it cant be the recommended method.  i am overriding the extractResponseData method of the Proxy and tricking the Model into believing that the server returned the exact same data (jsonData) that is already in the model.